# Geoserver ERROR: function postgis_lib_version()

Tags: postgresql, geolocation, postgis, geoserver

in geoserver whene i need to creat a new data store after to creat new workspace, i have this error

**Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: ERROR: function postgis_lib_version() does not exist Indice : No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position : 8**

Comment: please share some code

Comment: i don't do any code yet , i have juste my data base in postgres

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That error implies that you are attempting to add a *PostgreSQL* database rather than a *PostGIS* database. You need to add the PostGIS extension to the database with this command:

```
psql -d yourdatabase -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
psql -d yourdatabase -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;"
```

This will then allow you to store geometries (and geographies) in your tables which GeoServer can then display as map layers.