# i am failing to do geoserver conncetion to postgis

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, geoserver, geodjango

Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to obtain connection: ERROR: function postgis_lib_version() does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Geoserver ERROR: function postgis\_lib\_version()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38608510/geoserver-error-function-postgis-lib-version)

Comment: I tried that way and i continued to have the same error

Comment: please edit your question with details of exactly how you added the extensions - what happens in `psql` when you type `select postgis_lib_version();` ?